# Find the derivative of the function $f(x)=x/(x^2+1)$ at a point a

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$
I have to find the derivative and set a point by myself.
So I just set $x=a$ ( is it correct?)

and using the limit,
$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}  = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{a+h}{(a+h)^2 + 1} - \frac{a}{a^2+1}}{h}$$

therefore, the answer is $$\frac{ 1-a^2}{(a^2+1)^2}$$

is it correct?

Comment: do you know quotient rule?

Comment: @SaikatPanja  yes i know but the question is,, find functions at an arbitrary point.. i know i can just use that rule,, but the thing is i have to use an arbitrary point... that means i should use the definition of derivative.. right?

Comment: ummm okay. you surely can. but as $x^2+1>0$ so i think you can use the quotient rule also

Comment: yes it's perfect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29771/discussion-between-saikat-panja-and-kurtk3).

Comment: @kurtk3, I made some edits, feel free to adjust them if they are incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{x+h}{(x+h)^2+1}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1-x^2}{((x+h)^2+1)(x^2+1)}$$$$=\frac{1-x^2}{((x+0)^2+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

As far as I know, my answer also the same with the others. I guess you can substitute x=a. (not that important)

Answer (score 6):

> question is,, find functions at an arbitrary point.. i know i can just use that rule,, but the thing is i have to use an arbitrary point

$x$ is already arbitrary. **It doesn't get any more arbitrary by using a different letter as a variable name.** The whole point of a function is to associate one element of a set that you provide with another element (of a possibly different set).

And $x$ *is* any number of the real numbers (probably at least, you didn't specify what set $x$ comes from) without specifying which one. It's not $12$, not $-245234234.4564576$, it's **any** element of the set that the function "accepts". After all, this is why we use letters to denote some variable, because it's not one distinct number.

Comment: oh so no need to substitue x=a... but still the correct right? using a?

Comment: @kurtk3 you can name it whatever you want. It doesn't even have to be a single letter. So unless you don't like the letter x, there's no need to replace it with a, because as you say $x=a$, which means they are equal and can thus be replaced by one another. It's just a name which has **no influence whatsoever** on what rules you are allowed (or required) to use. The type or value of x (or a) can have an influence on that, but not the name. Math doesn't have rules like "_if you add two variables with letters later in the alphabet than k, you have to add an additional value of 5 to the result_"

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's question (perhaps due to the edit).

Comment: @shoover it answers the one in the comments which my answer quotes. Partial answers are considered ok as far as I remember.

Comment: Comments are subject to being deleted, so if you're going to answer a question that appears only in the comments, you might want to edit the Q to include the question that you're answering.

Comment: @shoover I quoted it for that reason

Answer (score 5):

Your answer is correct.

Notice, $$f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$

$$\implies f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{x+h}{(x+h)^2+1}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)(x^2+1)-x((x+h)^2+1)}{h((x+h)^2+1)(x^2+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^3+hx^2+x+h-x^3-2hx^2-h^2x-x}{h((x+h)^2+1)(x^2+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h-hx^2}{h((x+h)^2+1)(x^2+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1-x^2}{((x+h)^2+1)(x^2+1)}$$$$=\frac{1-x^2}{((x+0)^2+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}$$
Now, substituting arbitrary value $x=a$ 
$$f'(a)=\frac{1-a^2}{(a^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: What am I not seeing that everyone is jumping from stating the limit as a fraction with a lot of hs to the correct answer?  Is it obvious what the limit is.  I, personally, can't jump from that fraction to the result without doing a lot of tedious factoring, reduction, expanding first.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your comment is reasonable. So should I show some more steps to the final result of derivative ?

Comment: Well, not if the OP is happy.  I know how to do it (gad, it's tedious) and you know how to do it and apparently the OP knows how to do it because s/he wouldn't have had the correct answer.  I'm just ... well, not seeing the "show your work" part.  I tried to show it below and gad was it tedious and gad is it hard to read.  Suffice it to say "expand reduce the fraction and the h's become negligible and the result will follow".

Comment: Okay, maybe to show that the process is understood, an answer can go from the "large" untouched fraction to the fraction "tamed and reduced" but with the h values still in.  i.e$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{x+h}{(x+h)^2+1}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(1-x^2 -hx)}{(x^2 + 1)^2 + (2h + h^2)(x+1) }$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}  = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{a+h}{(a+h)^2 + 1} - \frac{a}{a^2+1}}{h} = \underbrace{\cdots \cdots \cdots \cdots \cdots \cdots \cdots}_{\text{and ?}} = \frac{ 1-a^2}{(a^2+1)^2} 
$$

In some contexts, jumping from the limit to its value without saying how it is derived is appropriate.  But here since you say the problem is to find the derivative, and normally one should include those specifics.  First some routine algebraic simplifications, then the crucial cancellation of the $h$, then substituting $0$ for $h$ in an expression that defines a continuous function.

Whether you should do this by finding a limit or by some other method (in this case, probably the quotient rule) also depends on the context, and you haven't told us about that.

Answer (score 0):

$\implies f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{x+h}{(x+h)^2+1}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}}{h}$

= $ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{x+h}{(x^2 + 1 + 2h +h^2}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}}{h}$

$f(x + h) - f(x) = \frac{x+h}{(x+h)^2+1}-\frac{x}{x^2+1} = \frac{(x+h)(x^2 -1)}{((x+h)^2+1)(x^2 + 1)}-\frac{x((x+h)^2+1)}{((x+h)^2+1)(x^2 + 1)}$

$= \frac{h(1-x^2 -hx)}{(x^2 + 1)^2 + (2h + h^2)(x+1) } $

so $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{h(1-x^2 -hx)}{(x^2 + 1)^2 + (2h + h^2)(x+1) }}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(1-x^2 -hx)}{(x^2 + 1)^2 + (2h + h^2)(x+1) } = \frac{1-x^2}{(x^2 + 1)^2}$

I don't know what "set a point" means unless it means try it for x = 0 or something. [In which case we'd get

$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{h}{h^2 + 1} -0}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h^2 + 1} = 1$

]